# jQuery hover for single element that is repeated

Tags: jquery, hover

I am trying to use jQuery to add a hover opacity on an element that is being repeated depending on how many items are in the database.

At the moment when hovering over one div, all of them are changing.

Here is the HTML/jQuery:
http://jsfiddle.net/RKhvv/1/

Apologies that the jsfiddle doesn't display any result but hopefully it is the best way of showing you the code.

Thanks!

Comment: Cleaned up your fiddle but the HTML doesn´t contain any element with the class `entryHeader`. http://jsfiddle.net/WTyGw/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

> ```
> $(document).ready(function() {        
>         $(".entryHeader").hover(function(){
>            $(this).stop(true).fadeTo("fast", 0.6); // This sets the opacity to 100%     on hover
>         },function(){
>             $(this).stop(true).fadeTo("fast", 1.0); // This sets the opacity back to 60% on mouseout
>         }); });
> ```

Answer (score 1):

Change your JavaScript to the following. The `$(this)` makes the `stop` calls apply only to the element being hovered over and not all elements with the `entryHeader` class.

```
$(document).ready(function() {        
    $(".entryHeader").hover(function(){
    $(this).stop(true).fadeTo("fast", 0.6); // This sets the opacity to 100% on hover
    },function(){
        $(this).stop(true).fadeTo("fast", 1.0); // This sets the opacity back to 60% on mouseout
    });
});
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5PTk7/) with the new code.

Answer (score 0):

You need to grab the current element that is being hovered on, not all with the same class.

I would loop around all the elements you have grabbed with the same class and then set each one individually